how to implement the room database library in new version catalog?
its showing me the error when, I am pasting the dependencies in the build . "Gradle. file". how to solve this ?see the screenshot of it and please guide me what to do next to solve this problem
I convert it to the new version catalog. but it showing me this "Lifecycle" is not a valid keyword. What to do guide me ?

I believe you have used the Quick fix and it caused the problem.
I explain this code as an example so you could fix it for other dependencies as well.
This is the room dependency:
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")

Navigate to

libs.versions.toml

Then define a key in [versions] section:
roomKtx = "2.6.1"

As you see after : we have room-ktx and we change it to roomKtx as our key and for value we consider its version.
Now the main step is left, in [libraries] section define it as below:
androidx-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "roomKtx" }

What happens here is that we create our key from androidx.room:room-ktx to androidx-room-ktx and for value we have arrays of group, name and version.ref keys.
For group from androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1 take items before : which are androidx.room. For name items between double : which are room-ktx and Finally for version.ref use the key defined in [versions] section which is roomKtx.
Now sync the file and go to build.gradles(Module :app).
Then change the implementation to :
implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)

And sync this file as well.
Done! ;)
If it fixes your problem please mark it as correct solution.
